# Is HTTPS supported with ConnectivityMode.Http on the Azure Servicebus

Tags: c#, ssl, azure, servicebus

I am trying to use `ConnectivityMode.Http` in a WCF Webservice to open a connection to the Azure servicebus relay using SSL (HTTPS). The connection appears to default to HTTP.

Is HTTPS supported from the WCF listener to the relaybus?

Thanks
Anthony

Comment: Note to self: Do not type publicly viewable messages on a Smartphone while walking and talking to someone, then submitting it without proof reading. Thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using SSL connection to set the connectivity mode at the AppDomain-level through the static ServiceBusEnvironment class you should be using TCP instead of HTTP as with TCP you can use port 9351 for SSL connection as described in [Service Bus Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh410102.aspx):

- **Tcp**  : Services create TCP connections with the relay service through port 9351 (SSL).
- **Http** : Services create an HTTP connection with the relay service making it easier to work around TCP port constraints.

Here is a list of supported [Service Bus Port Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee732535).

Answer (score 0):

Anthony, the present behavior of the ConnectivityMode flag is that if set to Auto, the listener will attempt to connect preferably using TCP, followed by HTTP. If set to ConnectivityMode.HTTP mode, it attempts an HTTP connection. In both these cases, clear HTTP is used. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode.aspx for details.

HTTPS support is planned, and information on this will be made available in due course.